Another 'TypeError: XXX.default is not a constructor' error
I define a class in one TypeScript file and I want to instantiate it in another but I get the error message TypeError: skillService_1.default is not a constructor.
I read many related Stack Overflow questions but none of them solves my issue. I suspected circular dependency but I checked my code with madge and there isn't any. Also in many posts default export was recommended but it doesn't solve my issue.
skillService.ts:
import ProgLangModel from '../models/progLang/progLangModel'
import { GitLabDiff, getGitLabFolders } from './versionControlService'
import isInPackageExclusionList from  '../config/packageExclusion'
import { Gitlab } from '@gitbeaker/core'
const similarity = require('../utils/stringSimilarity');

export default class TreeNode {

    private _name: string | null
    private _parent: TreeNode | null
    private _score: number | null
    private _progLangId: number | null
    private _children: TreeNode[]

    constructor(_name: string | null, _parent: TreeNode | null, _score: number | null, _progLangId: number | null) {
        this._name = _name;
        this._score = _score;
        this._children = [];
        this._parent = _parent;
        if (_parent)
            this._parent!.addToChildren(this)
        this._progLangId = _progLangId;
    }

    hasPackage(packageName: string): boolean {
    return this._children?.find(e => e._name === packageName) ? true : false;
    }
    ...

extractionService.ts:
import TreeNode, { populateSkillsFromContent, calculateCumulatedScore } from './skillService'
import log from '../models/progressLog/progressLogDataService'
import saveExtraction from '../models/extraction/extractionDataService'
import { getGitLabProjects, getGitLabCommits, getGitLabDiffList, getGitLabContentByCommitId, GitLabDiff } from './versionControlService'
import updateSkillTree from '../models/skill/skillDataService'
import saveProject from '../models/project/projectDataService'
import createGitLabApi from '../config/initGitLabApi'
import { Gitlab } from '@gitbeaker/core'
import { GitLabProjectType } from './versionControlService'

const start = async (repoId: number, branches: {}, path: string, progLangs: number[]) => {
    ...
    let skillTree: TreeNode = new TreeNode(null, null, null, null)
    ...

I haven't tried my application yet (I am in the early phase), the error arises when I run a test with Jest:
RUNS  services/extractionService.test.ts
Waiting for the debugger to disconnect...
/home/ubuntu/work/skillhunter/server/services/extractionService.ts:2415
      (cov_2dfwuq4qdi().s[55]++, new skillService_1.default(null, null, null, null));
                             ^

TypeError: skillService_1.default is not a constructor
    at /home/ubuntu/work/skillhunter/server/services/extractionService.ts:2415:34
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at fulfilled (/home/ubuntu/work/skillhunter/server/services/extractionService.ts:2291:24)

Node.js v20.9.0

In the test I don't refer to TreeNode.
What am I doing wrong?

My issue was that my TreeNode class was in a file with other functions that used this class. As soon as the class was moved to a separate file this error went away.
